# Bundle configuration: array node filled by default

Tags: php, symfony

I'd like to make some default configuration for my bundle. I want the user to be able to define:

```
apis:
    my-awesome-api:
        base_path: /foo
        title: Awesome API
```

And all the other information automatically filled. Another requirement is to have a default configuration in case the user didn't define any.

Here is what I tried:

```
->arrayNode('apis')
    ->isRequired()
    ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->arrayPrototype()
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('paths')->prototype('scalar')->end()->defaultValue([])->end()
            ->booleanNode('enable_doc')->defaultTrue()->end()
            ->scalarNode('doc_factory')->defaultNull()->end()
            ->scalarNode('base_path')->defaultValue('/')->end()
            ->scalarNode('title')->defaultNull()->end()
            ->scalarNode('description')->defaultNull()->end()
            ->scalarNode('version')->defaultValue('1.0.0')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

This code actually fills the configuration by default but only in case of values not null or empty. I'd like to have all keys "existing". Is it possible?

For now the default configuration look like this:

```
apis:
    main:
        base_path: /   # because default value is not empty or null
        version: 1.0.0 # because default value is not empty or null
        title: main    # because of main key
```

As you can notice, it's barely completed.

Comment: Look at this: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/dq1o/creating-a-custom-symfony-composer-bundle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addDefaultsIfNotSet()` function while building the configuration tree. For more details you can check here: 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#default-and-required-values

Comment: it changes nothing :(

Comment: addDefaultsIfNotSet() is not required here.  But the issue is from another part of my code after debug it looks like extension generate the correct configuration.